# Marked text (<b>) from a SQLite database won't get bold

Tags: android

i followed the answers of some questions here related to getting bold a specific part of text from an external sqlite database. i found a solution which require to add tags before and after the desired text ..adding them and adding Html.fromHtml in java file didn't change nothing ..thanks to correct me or show me a better method. ( and if you know how to change color, that would be great), PS: i have already made some research but wasn't lucky!

This is my code:

```
           TextView groupName = (TextView) view;
            String groupname;
            groupname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1));
            groupName.setText(Html.fromHtml(groupname));
```

this is a picture from the emulator showing the tags in text(UPDATED):
blob:https://imgur.com/aab1bc1c-4645-4124-8a68-97a949d5c227
EDIT1:
I've changed the text to `<b> or limen nasi </b>` but still no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the enclosing tag `</b>` at your example you have two opening tags `<b>` the second one should be closing.

Note that the following works:

```
groupName.setText(Html.fromHtml("aaa, <b> o mmm </b> smm"));
```

Android supports some HTML tags, to change text color there's also `<font color:#010203>text</font>`

Check if you returning correctly the value from SQLite

Comment: still, it didn't work ..i did it like this: <b> or limen nasi </b> but nothing changed

Comment: i did exactly what you asked(even for colors) with no result unfortunately blob:https://imgur.com/aab1bc1c-4645-4124-8a68-97a949d5c227 ..for returning correctly the value from SQLite ..you can check the code above..is like the one i found in answers..thanks for the answer

Comment: For: groupName.setText(Html.fromHtml("aaa, <b> o mmm </b> smm"));
it's not a good solution for me ..i'm extracting data from sqlite to an expendable list view ..i can't use this solution unfotunately

Comment: ..what do you think? you didn't provide me with opinion to my answers yet ..Thanks again

Comment: The piece of code was just for sample that it does works, I'm not sure what the problem is on the String you get from SQLite

Comment: ..it was a stupid mistake! i applied the fonthtml to the header (groupname) not to the child text(where the tags are) xD ! it works thanks ! for space between paragraphs and italic? how you do it please?

Comment: ```<p>``` or ```<br>``` for space and ```<i>``` for italic